Does the open mapping theorem hold for linear topological groups?
The open mapping theorem (of topological groups) states that a surjective continuous homomorphism of a locally compact Hausdorff group $G$ onto a locally compact Hausdorff group $H$ is an open map if $G$ is $\sigma$-compact. Generally, a subjective continuous homomorphism between topological groups may be not open. I am interested in the following cases: Let $f:A\to B$ be a continuous homomorphism of two Hausdorff topological fields. Then $f$ induces a continuous group homomorphism of topological groups $F:{\rm GL}_n(A)\to {\rm GL}_n(B)$. Suppose that $G$ (resp. $H$) is a closed subgroup of ${\rm GL}_n(A)$ (resp. ${\rm GL}_n(B)$), and $F$ induces a surjective continuous homomorphism $F:G\to H$. So, is $F$ an open map?

Take $n=1$, $B=\mathbb Q$ with standard topology and $A=\mathbb Q$ with discrete topology. Now, consider the identity homomorphism $f: A\to B$ and the induced homomorphism $F: GL_1(A)\to GL_1(B)$. I will leave it to you to verify that $f$ is continuous and $F$ is not open.
